# how to manage windows in external applications

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have 2 AIR applications (`A` and `B`) that are able to communicate via a `LocalConnection` object. I've verified that messages are definitely being sent/received appropriately.

I want to be able to have `A` tell `B` to come to the front. Both applications are full screen:

```
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1080, 1920);
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

I've tried several permutations, but as of yet nothing seems to work.

```
private function initSlave(channel: String): void {
    conn = new LocalConnection();
    conn.client = {
        'activateSlave': activateSlave
    };
    conn.allowDomain("*");
    conn.connect("_" + channel);
}

private function activateSlave(): void {
    stage.nativeWindow.orderToFront();

    // or

    stage.nativeWindow.activate();

    // or

    stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
    stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = false;
}
```

If I leave both applications in windowed mode (`stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL`), then toggling `alwaysInFront` actually works. Calling `activate()` or `orderToFront()` still do nothing. If I try to toggle `alwaysInFront` and then set the application to fullscreen, the application ends up fullscreen behind my windowed app. Maybe there is an event I should wait for before setting the app to fullscreen?

I found a thread mentioning that `orderToFront()` only works relative to windows within the same application, which explains why it doesn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone have any insights into pulling this off? Maybe there is a way for me to embed `B` into application `A` so they are actually the same application? I am not sure how to do this with an AIR application as simply as just loading the SWF due to requiring external resources.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue if both apps aren't full-screen?

Comment: I updated the question with a little bit of testing with windowed applications. `activate()` explicitly says in the docs that it should bring the window to front and gain focus, but I see neither behavior.

Comment: Does orderToBack() work? I'm thinking some sort of deactivated window issue.

Comment: I'm sure that `orderToBack()` has the same semantics as `orderToFront()`, in that it only affects windows owned by application `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one else has offered a solution, I'll just mention quickly the hack that I'm using. Basically I have 2 `LocalConnection` channels, one from `A` to `B`, and one from `B` to `A`.
The visible program (e.g. `A`) will then fade to white, set `visible` to `false`, and send a message to `B` giving up control. `B` has initialized itself with `stage.nativeWindow.visible = false`, and when it receives the message from `A` it goes visible as a full white screen and fades in the GUI. There is a slight offset before `A` sets `visible` to `false` to give `B` time to display, otherwise there is a pop in the brief moment when both windows are minimized.

Anyway, there you go, it's ugly but it actually works fairly well.